# How are images written to a web server (developing a custom web server in java)

Tags: java, server, network-programming

I am developing a web server(experimenting with network programming in java) using Java SE only, everything seems to be working well (i.e HTML and CSS files) but the problem is with images, they are written to browser as bytes with the correct mime type and the correct size but the problem is that they wont display on the web browser, its showing a black Screen, developers tool on Google Chrome shows the image has been properly downloaded with a status code of 200 OK and the correct file size . Below is my code.

```
        package miniserver;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.net.InetAddress;
        import java.net.ServerSocket;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.net.UnknownHostException;
        import java.util.Date;
        import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;

        enum status_code{
            OK(200),NOT_FOUND(404),FORBIDDEN(403);

            private int code;
            status_code(int code){
               this.code=code;
            }
            public int getCode(){
                return this.code;
            }
        }


        public class MiniServer {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

             try{

                 InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

                 try{
                     ServerSocket webserver = new ServerSocket(1521);
                     System.out.println("Web Sever Started");
                      System.out.println("Running On " + address.getHostAddress());




                     Date k= new Date();
                     System.out.println(k.toString());
                     Socket  browser ;
                     while(true){
                         browser=webserver.accept();
                         requestHandler handle = new requestHandler(browser);

                     }
                 }catch(IOException err){
                     System.out.println("Server Already Running"+err.getMessage());

                 }


             }catch(UnknownHostException ex){
                        Logger.getLogger(MiniServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }  

            }

        }
        class requestHandler implements Runnable{
            static int nRequest=0;
            private Socket client;
            private BufferedOutputStream stream;
             FileOutputStream out;
            BufferedOutputStream response;
            BufferedReader request;
            requestHandler(Socket client){
                try{
                   this.client=client;
                   this.response=new    BufferedOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
                   this.request=new BufferedReader(  new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                   new Thread(this).start();
                 }catch(IOException e){

                } 
            }



           @Override
            public void run(){

                try{

                    Scanner header = new Scanner(this.request);


                     String rf="";
                     String firstline=null;
                    try{
                     firstline=header.nextLine();
                     rf =firstline.split("\\s")[1].split("\\?")[0];
                     System.out.println(rf);

                    }catch(NoSuchElementException err){
                        System.out.println("NO HEADERS FOUND"+err.getMessage());

                    }

                    fileInputStream page;
                    fileInputStream errorpage=new fileInputStream("web/index.html");
                    status_code code=null;


                    String type="";
                    if(firstline.startsWith(".5.")){
                       page=errorpage; 
                       code=status_code.FORBIDDEN;
                    }else if(rf.equals("/")){
                        this.out = new FileOutputStream("test/index.html");
                        type="text/html";
                        page = new fileInputStream("web/index.html");
                        code=status_code.OK;
                    }else{
                        this.out = new FileOutputStream("test"+rf);
                        type = mime("web"+rf);
                        File local = new File("web"+rf);
                        if(local.exists()){
                            page=new fileInputStream(local);
                           code=status_code.OK;
                        }
                        else{
                            page=errorpage;
                            code=status_code.NOT_FOUND;
                        }

                     }
                     reply(code,page,type);


                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                }



            }
            void reply(status_code c,fileInputStream file,String type) throws IOException{

                StringBuilder head = new StringBuilder();
                head.append("HTTP/1.1 "+c.getCode()+" "+c+"\r\n");
                head.append("Date: "+ new Date().toString()+"\r\n");
                head.append("Server: Kilobyte MiniServer\r\n");
                head.append("Connection: close\r\n");
                head.append("Content-Type: "+type+" \r\n");
                head.append("Content-length: "+file.available()+"\n\r");
                head.append("\n\r");

                int length=head.length();

                for(byte b: head.toString().getBytes()){
                    this.response.write(b);    
                }

                int pageBytes;
                try{

                while((pageBytes=file.read()) != -1){
                    this.response.write(pageBytes);
                    this.out.write(pageBytes);

                    }
                file.close();
                this.response.close();
                this.request.close();



                }catch(IOException e){


                }
            }
            synchronized int incr(){
                 this.notifyAll();
                return ++nRequest;

            }

            String mime(String file){
                if(file.endsWith("css"))
                    return "text/css";
                else if(file.endsWith("html"))
                    return "text/html";
                else if(file.endsWith("js"))
                    return "text/javascript";
                else if(file.endsWith("JPG"))
                    return "image/jpg";
                else if(file.endsWith("jpg"))
                    return "image/jpg";
                else if(file.endsWith("jpg"))
                    return "image/jpg";
                else if(file.endsWith("png"))
                    return "image/png";
            return "text";
            }

        }
        class fileInputStream extends FileInputStream{
          String f;
          fileInputStream(String f) throws FileNotFoundException{
               super(f) ;
               this.f=f;
            }
             fileInputStream(File f) throws FileNotFoundException{
               super(f);
               this.f=f.toString();
            }  


            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return f;
            }

        }
```

Comment: _"they wont display on the browser"_ is insufficient description of the problem.  Explain clearly the symptoms.  Tell us what you've tried in the way of troubleshooting.  What do the developer tools on the browser tell you about the images that don't display? What does the network trace in the browser tell you? Are the MIME headers correct? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: The are mime (jpg) in the headers and a Status 200 OK but trying to view the image separately in a new tab  shows a black screen

Comment: Use the browser's debugging tools and examine the ACTUAL headers and data received.

Comment: The headers are corect

Comment: Compare everything with a real server's response.